# How To add Django template if condition in option tag

Tags: html, jquery, select, django-templates

I have created table and in that table I am doing Inline editing.

like mentioned in the image. [image]

So in the FuelZone Column I have to show dropdown list, with the selected value which is showing in the table before click on edit.

You can see in below image in the table on third row In `FuelZone` and `FuelType` column the data is showing `Spain_FZ` and `Diesel`.
[image]

But when I click on edit option it shows the different value in dropdown option. I want to set the option selected.

Code:

```
<td>
     <span class="editSpan fuel_zone">{{f.fuel_zone}}</span>
     <select class="form-control editInput fuel_zone" id="FuelZoneSelect" name="fuel_zone" style="display: none;">
     {% for c  in FuelZone %}
       <option value="{{c}}" {% if f.fuel_zone == c %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{c}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
       <option value="1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="1">Add New Zone</option>
       </select>
                          
      <small class="text-danger" id="err-fuel_zone"></small>
     </td>
```

How can I set option selected when I click on edi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Passing Queryset, So it wasn't getting selected.

Pass List in the forloop from views to django template. After Passing List the value is selected.

Views.py -

```
 fuel_zone = FuelZone.objects.filter(opco__in=opco_obj,status=True).all().values('fuel_zone')
    context["FuelZone"] = list(fuel_zone)
```

HTML Code -

```
 <select class="form-control editInput fuel_zone" id="FuelZoneSelect" name="fuel_zone" style="display: none;">
 {% for c  in FuelType %}
 <option {% if c.fuel_type == f.fuel_type %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{c.fuel_type}}">{{c.fuel_type}}</option> 
 {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Comment: can you prowide the code where you get the FuelZone queryset?

Comment: Hi @MaximDanilov . yes sure. I have edited my answer. You can see it.  before that I was passing without list() queryset. Now I am passing it with list()

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine, what happened.

But try this:

```
 {% for zone in FuelZone %}
 <option value="{{zone.id}}"
     {% if f.fuel_zone_id == zone.id %}
         selected="selected"
     {% endif %}>
           {{zone.title}}
 </option>
 {% endfor %}
```

what i did: i take `id` from fuelzone for option `value` and `title` from fuelzone for `visible text` in option

Comment: Hi @Maxir Thanks for the reply. I tried this code but its not gets option selected. How can I set selected option.

Comment: try do something like this. f.fuel_zone.id == zone.id. i dont know yor models, i can only imagine

Comment: Hey @Maxir Thanks for the reply. I got it. where exactly my fault is?

In the forloop, I was passing queryset thats why its not getting selected. 
Now I am passing list in the forloop, Its working now.

Comment: can you prowide the code how you get the FuelZone queryset?